# How to view/diff android source code using Smartgit

Tags: android, git, android-source, smartgit

I have android source code repo on UBUntu box. I am wondering what is the easiest way to open various git repos under android source tree using SmartGIT, a GUI git client.

One option is to open each folder that has .git manually from smartgit File->Open repo menu option.

Isn't there a better way to open all the repos in one shot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of SmartGit/Hg version 4, there is no other way than using Project|Open Repository.